# OutputStream / soapmessage To HTTP Post with Apache Camel

Tags: java, servlets, post, apache-camel

I am sending request to servlet which processing data like

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException { 
      // Decode incoming SOAP message 
      InputStream in = req.getInputStream(); 
...
```

Following is my client code for posting stream to servlet

```
SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage(); 
    ... 
OutputStream out = httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream(); 
soapMessage.writeTo(out);
```

Now i want to develop http client in Apache Camel to post like following

```
from("timer:foo?period=5s") 
    .process(   new Processor() {
               public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {       
                                            ... 
                   exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD,"POST"); 
                   exchange.getOut().setBody( soapMessage ); 
               } }) 
    .to("jetty:http://localhost:8180/app/sendStream");
```

EDIT:
I tried to run above code and face following error

```
org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Message1_1Impl to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Message1_1Impl@342a6d5a
   at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:177)
   at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.JettyHttpProducer.processInternal(JettyHttpProducer.java:166)
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? Have you put your soap message in the exchange body and tried to send it? What issues did you face?

Comment: Post updated i found No type converter available

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says. camel does not know how to parse/convert to the soap format you are using. It needs a typeconvertor to do so.
http://camel.apache.org/type-converter.html
You can use your own as shown in the doc:

```
Message message = exchange.getIn();
Document document = message.getBody(Document.class);
```

Or use convert the whole thing to String to just test that the route itself works.

However, since you are trying to parse SOAP which is XML you should unmarshal your message to SOAP instead. See here:

```
SoapJaxbDataFormat soap = new SoapJaxbDataFormat("com.example.customerservice", new ServiceInterfaceStrategy(CustomerService.class));
from("direct:start")
  .marshal(soap)
  .to("jms:myQueue")
```

From the documentation: http://camel.apache.org/soap.html